# PowerShell: Start-Process Firefox, how do he know the path?

Tags: powershell, start-process

When I call the following code:

```
Start-Process Firefox
```

Then the PowerShell opens the browser. I can do that with several other programs and it works. My question is: How does the PowerShell know which program to open if I type Firefox? I mean, Im not using a concrete Path or something ...

I though it has something to do with the environment variables ... But I cannot find any variable there which is called Firefox ... How can he know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I traced two halves of it, but I can't make them meet in the middle.

Process Monitor shows it checks the PATHs, and eventually checks `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe` so that's my answer to how it finds the install location, and then runs it.

That registry key is [for Application Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx) which says:

> When the ShellExecuteEx function is called with the name of an executable file in its lpFile parameter, there are several places where the function looks for the file. We recommend registering your application in the App Paths registry subkey.
>
> - The file is sought in the following locations:
> - The current working directory.
> - The Windows directory only (no subdirectories are searched).
> - The Windows\System32 directory.
> - Directories listed in the PATH environment variable.
> - Recommended: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

That implies PowerShell calls the Windows ShellExecuteEx function, which finds FireFox as a registered application, or it tries the same kind of searching itself internally.

---

Going the other way to try and confirm that, the [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849848.aspx) cmdlet has a parameter set called `UseShellExecute`. The 'Notes' of that help says:

> This cmdlet is implemented by using the Start method of the System.Diagnostics.Process class. For more information about this method, see [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) Method

Trying to trace through the source code on GitHub:

[Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Process.cs#L1710) is the PowerShell source code for `Start-Process`.

[Here, at this line](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Process.cs#L1939) it tries to look up the `$FilePath` parameter with `CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo`.

[Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Process.cs#L2097) it checks `else if (ParameterSetName.Equals("UseShellExecute"))`

Then [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management/commands/management/Process.cs#L2547) is the `.Start()` function which either starts it with `ShellExecute` or `Process.Start()`

OK, not sure if ShellExecute and ShellExecuteEx behave the same, but it could be PS calling Windows, which is doing the search for "FireFox".

That [`CommandSearcher.LookupCommandInfo` comes in here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandDiscovery.cs#L937) and follows to [`TryNormalSearch()`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandDiscovery.cs#L993) which is implemented [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandDiscovery.cs#L1173) and immediately starts a `CommandSearcher` which [has a state machine for the things it will search](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/309bf603f9aff9009dce7e725d42b2d4f99f58c9/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandSearcher.cs#L92)

- SearchState.SearchingAliases
- Functions
- CmdLets
- SearchingBuiltinScripts
- StartSearchingForExternalCommands
- PowerShellPathResolution
- QualifiedFileSystemPath

and there I get lost. I can't follow it any further right now.

- Either it shortcuts straight to Windows doing the lookup
- Or the PowerShell CommandSearcher does the same search somehow
- Or the PowerShell CommandSearcher in some way runs out of searching, and the whole thing falls back to asking Windows search.

  - The fact that Process Monitor only logs one query in each PATH folder for "firefox.*" and then goes to the registry key suggests it's not doing this one, or I'd expect many more lookups.
  - The fact that it logs one query for "get-firefox.*" in each PATH folder suggests it is PowerShell's command searcher doing the lookup and not Windows.

Hmm.

Comment: Holy! Thousand Thanks to you! Now I really learned something! Firefox.exe stands in the App_Paths in the registry. Another program  I installed on my Computer which was not listed there is found under $env:path. Thank You so much! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) I was able to trace the PowerShell. 
It first searches the `$env:path` variable, then the `$profile` variable.
In my case `firefox` wasn't found and then it searches through a whole lot in the Registry and somehow finds it.
It might have something to do with how firefox is installed on the system.